# Java applet displays itself multiple times

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I am making a Java applet for school whose function is to randomly select six numbers for coordinates of three points and connect them to make a triangle. It is only supposed to draw one triangle and find the "length of the sides". However when I put it on my website it will redraw itself multiple times.

[image]

I made another applet, simpler, that only selects 4 random numbers for coordinates to draw a line. Same problem.

The redrawing problem seems to happen when the user moves the screen, e.g. when I scroll or when I resize the applet viewer in Eclipse. My source code is posted here.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LineApplet extends JApplet {

    /**
     * Create the applet.
     */

    static int width;
    int height;


    public void init() {

          width = getSize().width;
          height = getSize().height;

       }

    public static int[] randomLine() {
        int[] pointArray = new int[4];
        int x;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            x = ((int)(Math.random()*(width/10-2)))*20+10;
            pointArray[i] = x;
        }
        return pointArray;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        int[] coords = new int[4];
        coords = randomLine();
        g.drawLine(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3]);
        g.drawString(coords[0]/10 + ", " + coords[1]/10, coords[0], coords[1]);
        g.drawString(coords[2]/10 + ", " + coords[3]/10, coords[2], coords[3]);
        int midpointx = (coords[0] + coords[2])/2;
        int midpointy = (coords[1] + coords[3])/2;
        g.drawString(midpointx/10 + ", " + midpointy/10, midpointx, midpointy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE call `super.paint(g)`.  This method does a lot of important work for you that will cause you problems in the long term if you don't respect it.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating new co-ordinates every time `paint()` is called.

`paint()` is called every time the applet window is resized or regains focus.

To fix, you could make

```
int[] coords = new int[4];
```

a class member variable and move

```
coords = randomLine();
```

to your `init()` method, which will only be called once upon initialization.

**Addendum:**

- Always call `super.paint(g);` when overriding `paint()`.
- For custom painting using Swing, the preferred approach is to extends a `JComponent` component leveraging the enhanced paint functionality offered by using `paintComponent`.

For more see: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: This is only masking the actual problem, while still an excellent suggestion, the OP is not respecting the component `paint` chain

Comment: Yes, while I would _strongly_ recommend to call `super.paint(g);`, this (the lack of this call) is not the reason why multiple co-ordinates are being generated.

Comment: True, but failing to call `super.paint` is going to result in the previous state begin re-generated.  So the two are related in this case - IMHO

Comment: Previous state won't really affect what is painted (as co-ords fixed from start when code fixed) but paint performance will be lousy :)

Comment: In this context, this is true, but you are still getting a dirty graphics context, if Swing has painted anything else to it, it will show up here.  Given the fact that's a top level container that has being overridden (yet another problem), it is very unlikely that this problem will present it self, but it's demonstrating bad practices (overriding a top level container's `paint` method and not calling `super.paint`) that will lead the OP down a slippery slope of probems... IMHO

Comment: I agree with everything you just said there :)

Comment: So to clarify- anything I put within the init() function will only run once, at the beginning, while everything I put in paint() will run every time it is resized?

In any case, I moved the functions to init() as suggested, thank you all so much for the help! I'm still learning, hopefully more of this will make sense later on!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For more follow the trail [Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Reimues, you are re-generating your coords each time the applet is repaint.

The other problem with your `paint` method is actually you're not clear the previous state of the graphics context (this would have being done by `paint`, but you failed to respect it's functionality when you overrode it).

You have two choices.

1. call `super.paint(g)`
2. call `super.paint(g)` and call [`Graphics#clearRect(int, int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [`Graphics#fillRect(int, int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

You should also, very rarely, need to override the `paint` method of top level containers.  One of the reasons is that they're not double buffered, the other is the paint chain is complex and easily broken...

You're better off using a `JPanel` (or such) and overriding the `paintComponent` method instead...

**UPDATED**

I updated your code to demonstrate the issues.

```
public class TestBadApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {

        final LinePane linePane = new LinePane();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton update = new JButton("Update");
        add(linePane);
        add(update, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                linePane.regenerate();
            }
        });

    }

    protected class LinePane extends JPanel {

        private int[] coords = new int[4];

        public void regenerate() {
            coords = randomLine();
            repaint();
        }

        public int[] randomLine() {
            int[] pointArray = new int[4];
            int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                x = ((int) (Math.random() * (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 10 - 2))) * 20 + 10;
                pointArray[i] = x;
            }
            return pointArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawLine(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3]);
            g.drawString(coords[0] / 10 + ", " + coords[1] / 10, coords[0], coords[1]);
            g.drawString(coords[2] / 10 + ", " + coords[3] / 10, coords[2], coords[3]);
            int midpointx = (coords[0] + coords[2]) / 2;
            int midpointy = (coords[1] + coords[3]) / 2;
            g.drawString(midpointx / 10 + ", " + midpointy / 10, midpointx, midpointy);
        }
    }
}
```

With `super.paintComponent`

[image: Good applet]

Without `super.paintComponent`

[image: Bad Applet]

Answer (score 0):

The trouble seems to be that [`paint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) is called every time the component needs repainting.

`paint()` methods should be written in a way that doesn't produce side effects and they shouldn't change the internal state of the applet. `paint()` must be restricted to doing just that: painting.

Comment: *"The trouble seems to be that paint() is called every time the component needs repainting"*, that's not a problem, that's how it works, but I understand what you're trying to say ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Haha, fair enough. It should read "The trouble with your code..."